# Finding the Corners of the an array of coordinates

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I have a 2D array of Coordinates in Numpy.

My goal is to attempt to find the corners (as if it were a square). So the :

Top left: smallest x, highest y
Top right: largest x, largest y
bottom left: smallest x, smallest y
bottom right: largest x, smallest y

Obviously each of these pairs need to consider the other values.

I was trying to take the min and max depending on the row:

```
        BottomLeft = np.min(np.min(hull, axis=1), axis=0)
```

However, this does not keep the pair of values together. It would have to be something like the smallest possible X values, and out of those, the smallest y value. Or something along these lines.
I am assuming there is efficient way to do this with numpy?

Here is an example of data:

```
    [[[260 156]]

 [[248 176]]

 [[235 197]]

 [[233 199]]

 [[192 199]]

 [[174 197]]

 [[160 171]]

 [[150 151]]

 [[154 149]]

 [[156 149]]

 [[260 151]]]
```

Thanks!

Comment: you could use `meshgrid`

Comment: how does that work?

Comment: it will create x, y pairs.

Comment: I already have x,y pairs though. THe function outputs that to me.. so that wouldn't really help me in my case :(

Comment: is the array elements like tuples of (x, y) or are there two different arrays one for x and the other for y

Comment: I don't think the problem will well-formed. The left-most point might not be the top most point for example. You said you'd first fid the smallest possible x-values and then, out of those, find the smallest y but there's no reason to think the smallest y is in the set of the smallest x-values.

Comment: @OliverDain I agree, but in this scenario i am assuming they are perfect squares.. so the left most point will have a value that could be the top most point. it will have a bunch of values at that left minimum, but I then need to find the highest value of that

Comment: @KhalilAlHooti it is a 2D array, so each entry is  [x, y]

Comment: If you have actual corners, you don't need to keep the coordinates paired. Absolute min and max will give you the coordinates you are looking for.

Comment: Providing sample data and defining constraints better will help get an answer.

Comment: but in this case I don't. I just want to search the list like i do. I'll edit my question

Answer (score 1):

Per the discussion above, this assumes that one of the pairs with the smallest `x` value will also correspond to the smallest `y` value. So you can first find the minimum x-value:

```
# Some sample data
d = np.array([[3, 1, 4, 1, 5],
              [8, 0, 4, 2, 3]])
# smallest value in the first row which, I assume, is your x-values
xm = np.min(d[0, :])
```

Then you can get the subset of values that have that minimum `x` value like so:

```
d[:, d[0,:] == 1]
```

So you can get the min of them via:

```
np.min(d[1, d[0,:] == 1])
```

Comment: you just updated your question and the rows and columns are reversed from what I was assuming above but the basic idea still works.

Answer (score -1):

suppose x coordinates are as follows

```
x = np.arange(0, 22, 2)
```

and suppose y coordinates are as follows

```
y = np.arange(20, 32, 2)

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)

yy = np.flip(yy, 0)

print(xx)

print(yy)
```

Then you can do whatever operation with xx and yy as they are coordinates.

for example,

let us assume z is the elevation

```
z = np.random.randint(2, high=20, size=(yy.shape[0], yy.shape[1])) # xx can also be used


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

plt.contourf(xx, yy, z)
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]