# How to find corners of several 3d points stored as numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am looking for an efficient way to extract four corners from several numpy arrays. I read [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60358730/finding-the-corners-of-the-an-array-of-coordinates) but could not solve my issue. My arrays are stored in a dictionary. These arrays and three column representing x,y and z coordinate. Each row is also a point and I have in some cases thousands of points. As my shows, I have here three sets with different colors and want to extract corners of each set. It should be noted that in reality I have tens of sets and each set I have thousands of point but still I want to extract four corners of each set. In the fig c stands for the corners, first number is set number and second numbers is corners number.
I copied my dictionary including two data sets here:

```
my_di={'sub_arr1': array([[50., 22.5, 28.53083253],
       [50., 7.5, 28.53022337],
       [41.23412371, 7.5, 10.],
       [41.22613668, 22.5, 10.],
       [50.69447517, 7.5, 30.],
       [50.6946373 , 22.5, 30.],
       [60.12217999, 7.5, 50.],
       [60.12265205, 22.5, 50.],
       [69.37286377, 7.5, 70.],
       [69.35833931, 22.5, 70.],
       [70., 22.5, 71.41123295],
       [70., 7.5, 71.37528419],
       [78.46719742, 7.5, 90.],
       [78.42491627, 22.5, 90.]]), 'sub_arr2': array([[60.79483509, 7.5, 30.],
       [51.35614872,  7.5, 10.],
       [60.7971096 , 22.5, 30.],
       [51.34645939, 22.5, 10.],
       [70., 22.5, 49.47742224],
       [70., 7.5, 49.50087547],
       [70.2344656 , 7.5, 50.],
       [70.24563313, 22.5, 50.],
       [79.53233719, 7.5, 70.],
       [79.53927994, 22.5, 70.],
       [88.7122488, 7.5, 90.],
       [88.69922638, 22.5, 90.]])}
```

from these two sets, I want to have the following results as the corners:

```
corners=[[[41.23412371, 7.5, 10.],
          [41.22613668, 22.5, 10.],
          [78.42491627, 22.5, 90.],
          [78.46719742, 7.5, 90.]],
          [51.35614872,  7.5, 10.],
          [51.34645939, 22.5, 10.],
          [88.69922638, 22.5, 90.],
          [88.7122488, 7.5, 90.]]]
```

I tried two ways to do do that but my results are not that much useful. Firstly the following code that takes the 4 farthest points in comparison with the center of mass of all points, but for the case that repartition is not symmetrical it does not work:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
four_c=np.array([])
for i in my_di.values():
    idx = np.argsort(distance.cdist([np.mean(i,axis=0)],i)).flatten()[-4:]
    f_c=i[idx,:]
    four_c=np.append (four_c, f_c)
four_c=four_c.reshape(int(len(four_c)/3),3)
```

when I print `four_c`, it give some other rows rather than four corners of each set.
Then, I tried a much more longer code:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
c1=np.array([])
c2=np.array([])
c3=np.array([])
c4=np.array([])
for i in dicti_ver_fault.values():
    corner1 = np.array(i.min (axis=0)) # this gives the row containing MIN values of x,y and z
    corner1 = corner1.reshape(1,3)
    c1=np.append(corner1, c1)
    corner2 = np.array([])
    corner3 = np.array([])
    corner4 = np.array(i.max (axis=0)) # this gives the row containing MAX values of x,y and z
    corner4 = corner4.reshape(1,3)
    c4=np.append(corner4, c4)
# the next block will find the corner in which x and y are minimum and z is maximum
    for j in i[:,0]:
        if j == max (i[:,0]):
            for h in i[:,1]: 
                if h == min (i[:,1]):
                    for k in i[:,2]:
                        if k == max (i[:,2]):
                            corner2 = np.append(corner2, np.array([j,h,k]))
                            corner2=corner2[0:3]
                            corner2 = corner2.reshape(1,3)
# the next block will find the corner in which x and z are minimum and y is maximum
    for m in i[:,0]:
        if m == min (i[:,0]):
            for n in i[:,1]: 
                if n == max (i[:,1]):
                    for o in i[:,2]:
                        if o == min (i[:,2]):
                            corner3 = np.append(corner3, np.array([m,n,o]))
                            corner3=corner3[0:3]
                            corner3 = corner3.reshape(1,3)
c1=c1.reshape(int(len(c1)/3),3)
c2=c2.reshape(int(len(c2)/3),3)
c3=c3.reshape(int(len(c3)/3),3)
c4=c4.reshape(int(len(c4)/3),3)
```

I cannot also find the absolute max and min of each column and use them, because in lots of cases corners are not absolute min or max values. I really appreciate any contribution.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find corners by the computing of vectors from point to both sides. After that, you compute the angle of these two vectors.

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
arr = [[50., 22.5, 28.53083253],
       [50., 7.5, 28.53022337],
       [41.23412371, 7.5, 10.],
       [41.22613668, 22.5, 10.],
       [50.69447517, 7.5, 30.],
       [50.6946373 , 22.5, 30.],
       [60.12217999, 7.5, 50.],
       [60.12265205, 22.5, 50.],
       [69.37286377, 7.5, 70.],
       [69.35833931, 22.5, 70.],
       [70., 22.5, 71.41123295],
       [70., 7.5, 71.37528419],
       [78.46719742, 7.5, 90.],
       [78.42491627, 22.5, 90.]]

comb = list(itertools.combinations(arr, 3))

line = []

#find the combination which have almost 0 or almost 180 degree angle
for points_arr in comb:
    points = np.array(points_arr)
    ba = points[0] - points[1]
    bc = points[2] - points[1]

    cosine_angle = np.dot(ba, bc) / (np.linalg.norm(ba) * np.linalg.norm(bc))
    angle = np.arccos(cosine_angle)
    if(np.degrees(angle) < 1 or np.degrees(angle) > 179):
        print(np.degrees(angle))
        line.extend(points_arr)
        break


#remove points in line from arr          
for point1 in arr:
    for point2 in line:
        #print(sum(np.array(point1) - np.array(point2)), point1, point2)
        if sum(np.array(point1) - np.array(point2)) == 0:
            arr.remove(point1)

#add other points in line          
for point1 in arr:
    ba = np.array(line[0]) - np.array(line[1])
    bc = np.array(point1) - np.array(line[1])

    cosine_angle = np.dot(ba, bc) / (np.linalg.norm(ba) * np.linalg.norm(bc))
    angle = np.arccos(cosine_angle)
    if(np.degrees(angle) < 1 or np.degrees(angle) > 179):
        line.append(point1)

#remove points in line from arr          
for point1 in arr:
    for point2 in line:
        #print(sum(np.array(point1) - np.array(point2)), point1, point2)
        if sum(np.array(point1) - np.array(point2)) == 0:
            arr.remove(point1)
```

I know that the code is not clear and many of it is duplication which can be modify to methods. This will move 7 points from `arr` to `line` and you can continue until `arr` will not be empty

Comment: Dear @Dalibor Cimr, I appreciate your solution. But, how can I find those four corners using you solution? I tried it. When I print `np.degrees(angle)` it gives me `90.00210334413676`. But can you please help me to understand ho I can find the corners?

Comment: 90 degrees means that these 3 points are not in one line. If another 3 points are in line, the result of the algorithm has to be over 180 degrees. I don't know how complicate shapes you have in your list of points (always rectangle or some robust polygon) but if you have just a list of points without sorting, you have to find several sets of points which are in one line (in case of the rectangle there are 4, in your case, it's two lines because the shorter side of the rectangle has no more points) and points on start and end of the line are corners

Comment: You mean I should run the code for all pairs existing in an array to find the 180 degrees result? My shapes are always almost planar rectangles or squares. They have always four corners. The issue is that maybe none of my points be in a line, how can I solve it? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Aha, What happens if none of them have 180 degrees? Can you please give your helpful idea as code to me. I am almost new in python and such stuff. I really appreciate your help and time.

Comment: Only two cases are without 180 degrees:

1) you have only four points - these points are corners

2) you have some robust polygon and not rectangle or square

Comment: My suggestion is:
```
1) use itertools.product() to find all combinations of three points
2) compute the angle of these combinations
3) if you find some three points with 180 degrees, save them as a line and add all other points which will have 180 degrees too (use two points from three of the product() result and add other to compute angle)
4) repeat from part 1) with the rest of points to find next line```

Comment: If you will have two lines, find two points of each line which have farthest euclidean distance (two points from two lines are three corners

If you will have three or four lines, find two points of each line which have farthest euclidean distance. You will have 6 or 8 points respectively where you have to find combinations of two corners from one line and one from other which have 180 degrees too. It means that this point is from  other line is your corner

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223017/discussion-between-ali-d-and-dalibor-cimr).